# Using " 's " after a Doxygen identifier

Tags: doxygen

I'm writing the documentation of a C project using Doxygen.
In the documentation of a function, one can refer to an argument of the function using `\p`. I want to use the " 's " possessive idiom in my text, e.g. writing `the object's name`. Here is a code sample that triggers the issue:

```
/**
 * @file
 * @brief Main C entry point
 * @author Vincent Siles
 */
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int foo;
    int bar;
} foobar;

/**
 * @brief blabla
 *
 * toto \p in's field foo.
 * toto \p in 's field foo.
 *
 * @param in    input
 */
void test(foobar *in)
{
    printf("%d %d\n", in->foo, in->bar);
}

int main(void)
{
    foobar xxx = { .foo = 0, .bar = 0};

    test(&xxx);
    return 0;
}
```

The generated HTML features:

```
<p>blabla </p>
<p>toto <code>in's</code> field foo. toto <code>in</code> 's field foo.</p>
```

As you can see, both `<code>` parts are unsatisfactory: the first one has the " 's " inside it and it feels wrong, and the second one has an additional space.

In this case, I could rephrase into `the field of \p in`, but that's not always possible. Is there a way to output `<code>in</code>'s field` ?

For the record, I'm using version 1.8.11, and I have this issue with the default configuration, created by doxywizard + optimize for C/PHP. The full configuration can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/kiqJe65N).

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using ?

Comment: I did a quick test with doxygen 1.8.13 and this looks OK to me, when you have problems with this version, please attach a small complete example including the changes between your configuration file (Doxyfile) and the standard configuration file.

Comment: Thank you @albert. I updated the question with more information.

Comment: I understand, it is about the variable "in" that you would like to show as code. The best I found was <code>in</code>

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with the `\p` command.
However, as a workaround you can use `` `in`'s `` instead of `\p in's`.

But note that it might look a bit weird since the `<code>in</code>` part will use a different font as the `'s` which therefore might appear bigger or smaller:

[image: code and normal text using different font]